# Serilog not logging information logs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, serilog

In my .NET Core 2.1 project I have installed `Serilog`, but for some reason it will not log information events. It logs error events, though.

In my appSettings I have:

```
    "Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Override": {
            "Microsoft": "Fatal",
            "System": "Fatal"
          }
        },
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "File",
            "Args": {
              "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
              "path": "D:\\Web\\098_VDSNet4\\Logs\\API.AdminPortal\\.txt",
              "rollingInterval": "Day"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

and in my Startup.cs I have:

```
                Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
                    .CreateLogger();

                services.AddLogging(logging =>
                    logging.AddSerilog(dispose: true)
                );
```

In the code I have:

```
            public IActionResult Post(Address address)
            {
                string functionName = "AddressController:Post";

                try
                {
                    logger.LogInformation($"{functionName}");

                    // TOOD Additional Address validation
                    addressRepository.Add(address);
                    addressRepository.Save();

                    return Ok(address);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.LogError(ex, $"{functionName}: There was an error creating the address");
                    return BadRequest();
                }

            }
```

`logger.LogInformation` (and I have tried `logger.LogDebug` as well, that doesn't work either) does not output anything. But `logger.LogError` does log the correct error.

I have tried changing the default level to Verbose to see if that would kick it into life, but I can't seem to get anything below Error to be output to the log file.

Comment: Yep, in the controller ctor I have ILogger<AddressController> logger

Comment: Do you have a second `.json` file, e.g. `appSettings.Development.json` or `appSettings.Production.json`, that's overriding the minimum level?

Comment: Also, I see you're using `AddSerilog()` - this has been mostly superseded by `UseSerilog()`, which avoids awkward interactions between Serilog and the default logger implementation; all the details are in: https://nblumhardt.com/2017/08/use-serilog/ - HTH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to inject the `ILogger<HomeController>` interface into your `HomeController` constructor.

```
    private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger _log;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _log = logger;
    }
```

You have to tell `asp.net core` from where to read the configuration (add this in `Program.cs`):

```
public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
            .Build();
```

In the Program.cs add `UseSerilog`:

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSerilog();
```

Results:

[image: Results for both Error and Information]

Comment: it is logging ok from program class. but in my controller it is not logging

Answer (score 0):

Inject your log into your controller through the constructor in order to use it.

```
using Serilog;

public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger _log;

    public MyController(ILogger log)
    {            
        _log = log;
    }

    public IActionResult Post(Address address)
    {
        //Make sure you are using the variable you set up in this controller
        _log.Information**("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: As I commented above the problem is not getting the logging to work. The problem is trying to get Information level logging to work. Errors are logged, but Information is not.

Comment: The overrides in your json will prevent a lot of information from being logged.  Also trying setting the default level to debug.

Comment: I tried setting the level to debug and verbose, but only Error gets written to the log file.

Comment: I have exactly same issue as mentioned by @NigelEllis, anyone have solution to this??
_log.LogError is perfactly writing logs to file as error but I want to write the log as information with methid _log.LogInformation() which is not writing anything to logs file...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the variable you create in your controller that is assigned in the constructor.  Do not use Logger.LogInformation.  Use _log.Information.  The logger that you are injecting is the one that you are configuring.  Logger.LogInformation is using the Microsoft logger not the serlilog that you set up.  Serilog would be .Information not .LogInformation.

Comment: When I type logger. in Visual Studio 2019 I do not get an option for Information; The intellisense gives me LogInformation, LogDebug etc. as well as Log<>. (This is .NET Core and not .NET Framework)

Comment: This is not using Serilog: private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger _log;